# How to merge these two maps into one

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to merge these two into maps into one. I tried to use concat but that is not working. and also tried var m = {...v1, ...v2}; but this also not working. So any one knows please help me.

And these are my two maps:

```js
var v1 = {Sdata: [{id: '1', name: 'Mark'},{id: '3', name: 'venu'}]};
var v2 = {Sdata: [{id: '2', name: 'Julee'},{id: '4', name: 'gopi'}]};
```

And here I'm excepting output is like below
If key matches it should merge like this

```js
result: Sdata: [{id: '1', name: 'Mark'},{id: '3', name: 'venu'}, {id: '2', name: 'Julee'},{id: '4', name: 'gopi'}]};
```

Comment: These don't look like ES6 `Map`s?

Comment: Please show us how you tried to use `concat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get all items in a single array with a dynamic approach.

```js
var v1 = { Sdata: [{ id: '1', name: 'Mark' }, { id: '3', name: 'venu' }] },
    v2 = { Sdata: [{ id: '2', name: 'Julee' }, { id: '4', name: 'gopi' }] },
    merged = [v1, v2].reduce((a, b) => {
        Object.entries(b).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (!a[k]) a[k] = [];
            a[k].push(...b[k]);
        });
        return a;
    }, {});

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Thanks for ans..but here data coming from back end and key will be dynamic..not all data key is 'Sdata'. So how can we merge generically.

Comment: you could reduce the an array of objects and group by same keys. pease see edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
const result = {
  Sdata: [...new Set(Object.values(v1).concat(Object.values(v2)))]
};
```

The Set is only used to remove duplicates from array.

Comment: Here keyname 'Sdata' is dynomic,  Even i want to eliminate duplicates so for dynamic key how to do..

Answer (score 1):

```
var v1 = {Sdata: [{id: '1', name: 'Mark'},{id: '3', name: 'venu'}]};
var v2 = {Sdata: [{id: '2', name: 'Julee'},{id: '4', name: 'gopi'}]};

var res = {Sdata: v1['Sdata'].concat(v2['Sdata'])};
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let v1 = {Sdata: [{id: '1', name: 'Mark'},{id: '3', name: 'venu'}]};
let v2 = {Sdata: [{id: '2', name: 'Julee'},{id: '4', name: 'gopi'}]};

let entries = Object.entries(v1).concat(Object.entries(v2));
let result = entries.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
    if(!acc.hasOwnProperty(currentValue[0])){
        acc[currentValue[0]] = [];
    }
    acc[currentValue[0]].push(...currentValue[1]);
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{ Sdata: [...v1.Sdata, ...v2.Sdata] }
```

The best thing about spread operator is its simplicity to get the required result without mutating the actual data.